# Why isnt char array first element ASCII in C

Tags: c

So i'm really new to C, but I have this homework and I can't figure out what's wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARR_LEN 4
#define HEX_LEN 16

int main (void)
{
    char input[ARR_LEN] = {0};
    char validHex[HEX_LEN] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    int i, j, isHex = 1;
    
    printf("Enter 4 elements: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    
    for (i = 0, isHex = 1; i < ARR_LEN && isHex == 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < HEX_LEN; j++)
        {

            printf("input(%c) == validHex(%c)\n", input[i], (validHex[j]));
            if ((input[i] == validHex[j])) 
            {
                isHex = 1; 
                break;
            }
            if (j == (HEX_LEN-1)) isHex = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It prints out this:

```
Enter 4 digits: 0110

input(0) == validHex()
input(0) == validHex(1)
input(0) == validHex(2)
input(0) == validHex(3)
input(0) == validHex(4)
input(0) == validHex(5)
input(0) == validHex(6)
input(0) == validHex(7)
input(0) == validHex(8)
input(0) == validHex(9)
input(0) == validHex(A)
input(0) == validHex(B)
input(0) == validHex(C)
input(0) == validHex(D)
input(0) == validHex(E)
input(0) == validHex(F)
```

So it seems to me as the first element in validHex[HEX_LEN] can't be read or something like that.
The goal of the program is to determine wether the string is in hex or not.

Comment: To enter 4 elements using the conversion specifier %s you need an array with 5 elements due to the terminating zero of the entered string.

Comment: The problem is that you forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. The array `input` only have space for *three* characters, plus the null-terminator. When you use `scanf("%s", input);` to read four characters, the null-terminator will be written out of bounds of the `input` array, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Agree - it's probably overwriting the first element of the reference array. Care to write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your array is too short.
2. You scanf may write outside the array bounds
3. You past the string (you need to check the inputted string length)
   and some small changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARR_LEN 20

int main (void)
{
    char input[ARR_LEN];
    char validHex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    int i, j, isHex = 1;
    
    printf("Enter number: ");
    fgets(input, ARR_LEN, stdin);
    printf("\n");
    
    for (i = 0, isHex = 1; i < strlen(input) && isHex == 1; i++)
    {
        isHex = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < sizeof(validHex) - 1; j++)
        {
            if ((input[i] == validHex[j])) 
            {
                isHex = 1; 
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isHex)
            printf("input('%c' dec(%d) ) == validHex(%d)\n", input[i], input[i], j);
        else
            printf("input('%c' dec(%d) ) is not valid Hex\n", input[i], input[i]);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rKW5en